# Is it possible to modify the value of a char* in .rodata section of an elf?

Tags: linux, elf, disassembly, patch

I know you can easily patch the ELF with a value of the same size. 
But, what if I want to change it for a bigger value? Is there a way to un-pack and re-pack the ELF?

I'm not interested in patching the binary in memory.

Comment: So you want to resize a string? This is certainly possible in principle, but since it may overlap with other raw data (e.g. C-style strings "asdf" and "sdf" overlap) due to compiler/linker optimizations, you might have more luck with adding a new value to do .rodata section and changing all required references to the old .rodata value, to the new location. Either way this is not an easy task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, what if I want to change it for a bigger value?

You apparently want a *longer* string, not a bigger value.

> is there a way to un-pack and re-pack the ELF?

Depends on what kind of `ELF` you are asking about. If you have a relocatable object file of type `ET_REL` (usually `.o`), then modification is fairly trivial: you simply append a new section to the end of the file (usually string contents reside in `.rodata` section, so you would make a (larger) copy of it, and then update corresponding section header's `.sh_offset` and `.sh_size` to point to the right place in the file.

On the other hand, for a *linked* `ELF` binary (`ET_DYN` or `ET_EXEC`), the task is so complicated as to be very hard (nearly impossible), because multiple pointers would need to be updated, and the placement in memory is not arbitrary.